# Comparing arrays and selecting best match in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to compare a user submitted form via ajax that will compare the selections made against available products, and choose the best one for the given options selected

the products are organized within an array

```
$tour = [
 ["id" => "894", "name"=>"Polynesian Cultural Center Super Ambassador Luau",   "greeting"=> true,"canoeRide"=>true,"behindScenes"=>true,"dvd"=>true,"desert"=>true,"tourGuide"=>true,"dinner"=>3, "seatingLevel"=>3,"combo"=>false],    
 ["id" => "897", "name"=>"Polynesian Cultural Center - Ali'i Luau", "greeting"=> true,"canoeRide"=>true,"behindScenes"=>false,"dvd"=>false,"desert"=>false,"tourGuide"=>false,"dinner"=>2, "seatingLevel"=>2,"combo"=>false],
 ["id" => "900", "name"=>"Polynesian Cultural Center - Admission and Show", "greeting"=> false,"canoeRide"=>false,"behindScenes"=>false,"dvd"=>false,"desert"=>false,"tourGuide"=>false,"dinner"=>0, "seatingLevel"=>1,"combo"=>"basic"],
 ["id" => "901", "name"=>"Polynesian Cultural Center - Ambassador Ali'i Luau", "greeting"=> true,"canoeRide"=>true,"behindScenes"=>false,"dvd"=>true,"desert"=>true,"tourGuide"=>true,"dinner"=>3, "seatingLevel"=>2,"combo"=>false],
 ["id" => "805", "name"=>"Pearl Harbor/Dole Plantation/Polynesian Cultural Center", "greeting"=> false,"canoeRide"=>true,"behindScenes"=>false,"dvd"=>false,"desert"=>false,"tourGuide"=>false,"dinner"=>2, "seatingLevel"=>2,"combo"=>"pearlDole"],
 ["id" => "931", "name"=>"North Shore and Polynesian Cultural Center With Luau and Show", "greeting"=> true,"canoeRide"=>true,"behindScenes"=>false,"dvd"=>false,"desert"=>false,"tourGuide"=>false,"dinner"=>3, "seatingLevel"=>2,"combo"=>"northShore"],
 ["id" => "807", "name"=>"Polynesian Cultural Center/Dole Plantation and North Shore", "greeting"=> true,"canoeRide"=>true,"behindScenes"=>false,"dvd"=>false,"desert"=>false,"tourGuide"=>false,"dinner"=>1, "seatingLevel"=>0,"combo"=>"dole"],
 ["id" => "898", "name"=>"Pearl Harbor and Polynesian Cultural Center with Luau and Show", "greeting"=> true,"canoeRide"=>true,"behindScenes"=>false,"dvd"=>false,"desert"=>false,"tourGuide"=>false,"dinner"=>2, "seatingLevel"=>2,"combo"=>"pearl"],
 ["id" => "815", "name"=>"Ultimate Hawaii Experience Package", "greeting"=> true,"canoeRide"=>true,"behindScenes"=>false,"dvd"=>false,"desert"=>true,"tourGuide"=>false,"dinner"=>2, "seatingLevel"=>2,"combo"=>"all"],
 ["id" => "879", "name"=>"Pearl Harbor and Hawaiian Luau Package", "greeting"=> true,"canoeRide"=>true,"behindScenes"=>false,"dvd"=>false,"desert"=>false,"tourGuide"=>false,"dinner"=>2, "seatingLevel"=>1,"combo"=>"pearl"],
 ["id" => "1029", "name"=>"3-Day Oahu Sightseeing Experience Package", "greeting"=> true,"canoeRide"=>true,"behindScenes"=>false,"dvd"=>false,"desert"=>false,"tourGuide"=>false,"dinner"=>2, "seatingLevel"=>2,"combo"=>"all"]
 ];
```

the object that I am trying to compare against these products is:

```
  {"id":null, "name":"null", "greeting":true,"canoeRide":true,"behindScenes":false,"dvd":true,"desert":true,"tourGuide":false,"dinner":null, "seatingLevel":null,"combo":"dole"};
```

the object will be changed dynamically based on user input, this is just an example.

What is the best way to go about the comparison operation?

Comment: Define 'best match'. What are you most interested in getting right?

Comment: the particular matches don't have any precedence, I'm simply looking to narrow down the first array to a single selection based on the user given criteria.

Comment: You have to have some idea of what you want to do - otherwise a valid way to define 'best match' is 'pick one at random'. It narrows the first array down to a single selection based on the user given criteria. (I'm sure you intuitively know what it should look like and just don't know how to write your intuitions down, though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the item which has the most in common with the input?

```
function distance($a, $compare_with) {
    $in_common = 0;
    foreach ($compare_with as $key => $value) {
        $in_common += ($value == $a[$key]);
    }
    return $in_common;
}

function most_in_common($object_list, $compare_with) {
    $in_common = array();
    foreach ($object_list as $key => $val) {
        $in_common[$key] = distance($val, $compare_with);
    }
    return $object_list[array_search(max($in_common), $in_common)];
}
```

Comment: You know it would be very helpful if you gave valid json to play with. Anyway, in your example, the most matching with 5 matching attributes was `{"id":"807","name":"Polynesian Cultural Center\/Dole Plantation and North Shore","greeting":true,"canoeRide":true,"behindScenes":false,"dvd":false,"desert":false,"tourGuide":false,"dinner":1,"seatingLevel":0,"combo":"dole"}`

Comment: thanks a lot, my initial thought was to use a counter similar to this but i couldt figure out how to implement it

Comment: Plugged it in? I manually edited your text into valid Json by replacing a lot of [ into { and => into :. Used Json_decode to read it into a hash.